# BluetoothAdapter: How do I know if no BLE devices are found after startLeScan()?

Tags: android, callback, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am developing an Android app to record the RSSI fluctuations from a BLE beacon. I use the `startLeScan(BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback callback)` method and from the callback get the RSSI value every time the beacon is discovered (till I have some `MAX_NUM` values). Then I call `stopLeScan()`.

However, I also want to know whenever the app performs a scan but is unable to discover the beacon during this period. As I understand, this will result in the `onLeScan()` callback not being invoked. How can I do this?

Comment: Well, just save to a variable that the onLeScan() callback was called in the onLeScan() callback, and then check that variable when you stop the scan?

Comment: @Emil But this wouldn't tell me how many times onLeScan() callback was NOT called in comparison to how many times it was. I want both of these numbers.

Comment: The onLeScan method will always be called for every valid advertisement received by the Bluetooth controller. So I don't really understand your question. If your beacon advertises but your Android device can't see it, you can't know that it actually advertised.

Comment: I am talking about when the Bluetooth controller does not receive an advertisement, as in when the beacon moves out of range and then back into range.

Comment: If it is out of range to be detected, how would you know if it was advertising or not? Sorry but I still don't get your question. The Bluetooth controller delivers everything it knows to you.